# XSD to enforce either or both Elements available in XML

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

Using below XSD, I want to enforce that in my XML:
1. either D Element is available
2. or E element is having F as its child. And F element is having G Attribute with H value.
3. or both 1 and 2 Conditions are satisfied

But i am not able to find any way to acheive it.
Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

```
    <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <xs:element name="A">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="B" minOccurs="1">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element name="C" minOccurs="1">
                    <xs:complexType>
                      <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="D"/>
                        <xs:element name="abc"/>
                        <xs:element name="E">
                          <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:sequence>
                              <xs:element name="F">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                  <xs:simpleContent>
                                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                      <xs:attribute name="G" use="required">
                                        <xs:simpleType>
                                          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                            <xs:enumeration value="H" />
                                          </xs:restriction>
                                        </xs:simpleType>
                                      </xs:attribute>
                                    </xs:extension>
                                  </xs:simpleContent>
                                </xs:complexType>
                              </xs:element>
                            </xs:sequence>
                          </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                      </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                  </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
```

Thanks,
Akash

Answer (score 0):

The type of validation you require is of dynamic behavior. The XSD cannot do this sort of validation. However, there's another standard [Schematron](http://schematron.com/), that can perform dynamic validation.

> **What is Schematron?**
>
> A language for making assertions about the presence or absence of patterns in XML documents.

Below is the sample XSD that utilizes **Schematron** language:

```
<xs:element name="sampleElement" type="sampleElement_Type">
<xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
        <sch:pattern name="Co-occurrence constraint on attribute Title" xmlns:sch="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron">
            <!--<sch:rule context="sampleElement">-->
            <xs:attribute name="Attr1" use="required" form="unqualified">
                <xs:simpletype>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:enumeration value="XYZ" />
                        <xs:enumeration value="PQRS" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpletype>
            </xs:attribute>

            <xs:attribute name="Attr2" use="required" form="unqualified">
                <xs:simpletype>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:enumeration value="ABC" />
                        <xs:enumeration value="DEF" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpletype>
            </xs:attribute>
            <sch:rule context="*[@Attr1]">
                <sch:assert test="(@Attr1 = 'XYZ' and @Attr2 = 'ABC')">If the Attr1 is "XYZ" then the Attr2 must be "ABC".</sch:assert>
            </sch:rule>
            <sch:rule context="*[@Attr1]">
                <sch:assert test="(@Attr1 = 'PQRS' and @Attr2 = 'DEF')">If the Attr1 is "PQRS" then the Attr2 must be "DEF".</sch:assert>
            </sch:rule>
        </sch:pattern>
    </xs:appinfo>
</xs:annotation>
```

This schema asserts the following rules:

1. If value of attribute `Attr1` is `XYZ`, then the value of attribute `Attr2` should be `ABC`.
2. If value of attribute `Attr1` is `PQRS`, then the value of attribute `Attr2` should be `DEF`.